# SOQL query with Dataloader using List Literal in WHERE Clause

Tags: soql, data-loader, data-export

Is it possible to construct a SOQL query with a list literal in the WHERE clause? My use case is that the data loader cannot handle child relationships/subqueries needed for my search, but I can get the full list of IDs to export and would like to submit a query along the lines of

```
[Select Id, Name, ... from Account WHERE Id in ('Id1', 'Id2',... ) ]
```

Since this is the DataLoader, I can't just use a variable list either. Or does someone know an alternate way to export queried data?

Comment: Your question subject and content seem to disagree with each other, but you absolutely can include a comma separated list in a WHERE clause using `IN('Id1','Id2,...)`

Comment: Someone edited my title to make it incorrect. Fixed.

Comment: How many elements may your list have (top limit if you have in mind) ?

Comment: Several thousand. For what I'm looking at currently, ~3000, but in principle up to 10k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot get an answer or the list in lengthy, What I have done in the past is:

1. Create  boolean Flag named ExtporData__c on the object
2. Updated all accounts via data loader using CSV with ID and ExportData__c field that should be exported

then in the data loader for export I simply used EmportData__c = true in the where clause

Comment: Ah, that's clever. If it comes to it, I'll do that.

Comment: Fields like this are extremely useful, I might recommend using a number or text field though in case you ever have a case where you need to compare multiple sets of records. In our org, we have a field called temp__c on pretty much every object for this sort of scenario. Of course, you'll only want to make this available to admins though...

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got the answer yet, Try these steps :

1. Query all possible Id's which should be included in your IN Clause.
2. Use notepad++ to add '' into each id's and an use this in the [edit] SOQL statement.
3. In Data loader just replace this query and export.