# Data deletion with Attachments using Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, dataloader-batch

what should be the best practice to delete records and it's related attachments using Dataloader. As I understand, attachments are not getting deleted when you delete the parent record. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to find a way to single out the attachment records of those objects you wish to delete (likely match the IDs of the records to the `ParentId` on the Attachment record - object reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm)).  [Ragesh's answer on this question may help you in figuring out how to do so](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84169/soql-query-with-dataloader-using-list-literal-in-where-clause).  Then, follow the instructions of the [Mass delete attachments with Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325228&type=1) knowledge article.